# Too much org.apache.axis written to Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, soap, console, axis

In Eclipse Juno, I have a web service client.  It is working, but the org.apache.axis is writing a huge amount of output to the console, like this:

[org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] : org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(pushHandler00)
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Pushing handler org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer@1f6226
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Exit: DeserializationContext::startElement()
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Enter: DeserializationContext::endElement(http://nj.ids.clps, getVersionReturn)
[org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] : org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(popHandler00)
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Popping handler org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer@1f6226
[org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] : org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setValueInTarget00)
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl] : Set value 1.0.11.4 ICW Web Service in target org.apache.axis.message.RPCParamTarget@64ea66
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Popped element stack to org.apache.axis.message.RPCElement:getVersionResponse
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Exit: DeserializationContext::endElement()
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Enter: DeserializationContext::endElement(http://nj.ids.clps, getVersionResponse)
[org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] : org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(popHandler00)
[org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext] : Popping handler org.apache.axis.message.RPCHandler@1901437
[org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle] : org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setProp00)

Does anyone know how to control this output?

Comment: How are you running it, e.g. is it in tomcat or Jboss or some other app server?

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is fixed by configuration of the logging library.

All loggers that start with the name `org.apache.axis` will be set to log level **WARNING**

- **Log4j** XML configuration (`log4j.xml` or `log4j2.xml`)

  ```
  <Logger name="org.apache.axis" level="warn" />
  ```
- **Slf4j** XML configuration (`logback.xml` or `logback-test.xml`)

  ```
  <logger name="org.apache.axis" level="WARN" />
  ```